# Mod_ReWrite doesn't work on cakephp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have recently deployed CakePHP however mod_Rewrite is not currently working:

I have the following in my apache2.conf

```
<Directory "/path/to/the/app">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

i have run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

which stated the module is already enabled and i have also checked the .htaccess file which has

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

has anyone got any other ideas as to why mod_rewrite isn't working?

Please note i have restarted apache with no sucess

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting errors? Have you checked your logs? Is there an htaccess file in your webroot directory?

Comment: yes the .htaccess file is in the folder /var/www/site/App which is the same as set in the apache2.conf and no errors other then the default cakephp page stating that "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server."

Comment: Is there a `webroot` directory in your `/var/www/site/App` directory?

Comment: @JonLin yes there is a webroot in there looked at error.log in the apache logs and there is not error what so ever

Comment: Try to add  this row `RewriteBase yourpath` to your .htaccess, where yourpath is the path inside your /var/www directory.

Comment: I assume that would be after the RewriteEngine On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out mod_rewrite was working, however I was using cakephp 1.3 which doesn't detect if the mod_rewrite works but applys a CSS style which wasn't applying to the div. it works now anyways

Answer (score 0):

There must be 3 .htaccess files in these locations

```
/.htaccess
/app/.htaccess
/app/webroot/.htaccess
```

Do you have them?